# Historical key ratios for companies

Tags: python, finance

Is there any convenient way to get key ratios over time for companies? A good API perhaps? When using Yahoo finance I managed to get the latest key ratios but not historical values. I can't find a way to do that. Can somebody please give some advice? FYI: I'm using python.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to get these key ratios:

- Using Eikon or Bloomberg API's (but none for python from my knowledge) if you could have access to an authenticated account
- Downloading historical ratios from WolframAlhpa ([MSFT Example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%2Fe%20msft)),
- Or downloading key ratios from MorningStar ([Coca-Cola Example](http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=KO)) with 10 years of historical data

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it much myself, but [quandl](https://www.quandl.com/) looks pretty cool. You can pull stuff directly into Python, R, Excel, Matlab, and a bunch of other environments with an api that retrieves csv, xml, or json. Makes it look pretty easy for some problems.